# Display views of web page today month and year with PHP without adding to DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table `views` for keeping track of views on a web page. The table is structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE views (  
    id int(11) not null auto_increment,
    page int(11) not null,
    pglast DATETIME not null,
    pgviews int(11) default 0,
    primary key(id),
    unique key page (page)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The `page` column is the ID of the page that is viewed, the `pglast` column is for saving when the page was last visited. `pglast` typically looks like:
`2018-12-03 14:57:57`

The `pgviews` column is for saving how many visits there were, this column typically looks like:
`7`

I am **not** adding rows every time a page is visited, but simply `UPDATE` the record: I update the `pglast` column and increment `pgviews` column.

What I want:
display the amount of views for today, this month and entire year.

Is it possible to do what I want, or do I have to add rows for the visits, with the visit date? The disadvantage of adding rows on page visit is of course that it can get quite full if there are a lot of visits, whereas simply UPDATING the record is more scalable...

Comment: With your current way of saving data in the table, you can only get the total number of views till date. You cannot get historic information. For that, you will need to store every view details as an individual row

Comment: Yes I was afraid of that. I guess I will have to change it to insert a row on each page visit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want without adding a row for each visit you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE views (  
    id int(11) not null auto_increment,
    page int(11) not null,
    pglast DATETIME not null,
    pgviews int(11) default 0,
    pgviews_day int(11) default 0,
    pgviews_month int(11) default 0,
    pgviews_year int(11) default 0,
    primary key(id),
    unique key page (page)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Increment pgviews_day, pgviews_month and pgviews_year with every visit. Run a cronjob that resets pgviews_day, pgviews_month and pgviews_year every day, month and year respectively.